# can you please explain the output of this code? and how to use where function in numpy?

Tags: pandas, numpy, where-clause

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.where(a<4)
```

answer:

```
array([0,0,1]), array([0,1,0])
```

please explain output:

answer:

```
array([0,0,1]),array([0,1,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

[`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) gives you the indices of the truthy values.

I hope this break down helps you to understand the logic:

```
a = np. array([[1,2],[3,4]])
#         0  1
# array([[1, 2],   # 0
#        [3, 4]])  # 1

a<4
#            0      1
# array([[ True,  True],    0
#        [ True, False]])   1


# flat version
# row:          0     0       1      1
# col:          0     1       0      1
# # array([[ True,  True], [ True, False]])

# keep only the True
# row:  [0, 0, 1]
# col:  [0, 1, 0]

np.where(a<4)
# (array([0, 0, 1]), array([0, 1, 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` returns a tuple with (in this case) 2 elements.

The first element are row indices of elements meeting the condition.

The second element are column indices of elements meeting the condition.

To check it, save the result, e.g.:

```
ind = np.where(a < 4)
```

Now, when you run `a[ind]`, you will get a (1-D) array filled with elements
meeting this condition, i.e.:

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

If your source array has more dimensions, the resulting tuple
will have more components.